# Set / Case When value Like

Tags: sql

Until now I updated the value field on my database like this :

```
            'UPDATE lignefraishorsforfait '
            . 'SET lignefraishorsforfait.libelle = CONCAT("REFUSE : ", libelle) '
```

However, I would like to make a check to avoid that the " REFUSE " value is present several times. If it presents already, value keeps the same. If it not, then CONCAT with "REFUSE". I tried this :

```
            'UPDATE lignefraishorsforfait '
            . 'SET lignefraishorsforfait.libelle = '
            . 'CASE WHEN libelle LIKE "%REFUSE%" THEN libelle ELSE CONCAT("REFUSE : ", libelle) END,'
```

However this is not working as libelle stay the same (I made a test with a line not containing the value "REFUSE").
Also with '' instead of "", it is throwing an error

Could you help me ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma:

```
UPDATE lignefraishorsforfait 
    SET libelle = (CASE WHEN libelle LIKE '%REFUSE%' THEN libelle ELSE CONCAT('REFUSE : ', libelle) END);
```

However, you should shorten this to:

```
UPDATE lignefraishorsforfait 
    SET libelle = CONCAT('REFUSE : ', libelle)
    WHERE libelle NOT LIKE '%REFUSE%';
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me ! I just tried but with no result...? I'm using PhpMyAdmin and when i'm using '' instead of "" I have errors like undefined constant for "REFUSE" ...

Comment: @SidGabriel . . . You can use double quotes if they work for you.  I don't understand why -- single quotes are the SQL standard for string constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE lignefraishorsforfait 
          lignefraishorsforfait.libelle = 
          CONCAT("REFUSE : ", libelle)  where libelle not like 'REFUSE : %';
```